# Magento 1.9.2 - Accessing an External Database an another domain

Tags: magento-1.9, database, domain

On my site with Magento installed, I can't call up the database that is present on another domain. I wish I could have one database for multiple sites with Magento.

How can I retrieve the database with my site with Magento which is present on another domain?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:94:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known";i:1;s:1836:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/new/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()

Comment: are you sure you have correct hostname/ip ?

Comment: Yes man, I also checked now, but without success.

Comment: check you have permission to access mysql outside of your host

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct config for databse host in app\etc\local.xml file

```
<host><![CDATA[your-host-ip]]></host>
```

**OR**

```
<host><![CDATA[your-host-full-url]]></host>
```

and check you have permission to access mysql outside of your host

If it still not solve your problem check [DNS Issue](http://albertech.net/2011/05/fix-php_network_getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your magento with multistore.

You can point your each store with multiple domain with one database.

Read this guide : http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/store-hierarchy.html

open up the index.php file and look for this line (it's the last line of the file):

> Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

Add the following code right before the above code:

> $mageRunCode = 'YOUR_WEBSITE_CODE';
>
> $mageRunType = 'website';